# Why is $\mathbb{C}^n = N((A - \lambda_1I)^{n_1}) \bigoplus ... \bigoplus N((A - \lambda_sI)^{n_s})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**In short** I want to know why the fact stated in the title is true and I would need it explained in "basic" linear algebra language.

**The full context:**
I have just started a course on ODE's and this theorem about building $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the generalised eigenspaces corresponding to the algebraic multiplicity of each respective eigenvalue of A is given as a footnote without proof. I would like to understand it.

I have only read "basic" linear algebra and as such am not comfortable in the sort of endomorphism, range, kernel and field type arguments I have found online. I should note that I have also recently studied basic group theory so some of these concepts are still familiar to me within that context.

**My attempt at a solution:**
We need to show,
if $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then $v = c_1v_1 + ... + c_sv_s$, where $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $v_i \in N((A - \lambda_iI)^{n_i})$ for all relevant i.
i.e. that
i) $v_1, ..., v_s$ are linearly independent,
ii) ${v_1,...,v_s}$ span $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Assume they are linearly dependent, i.e.
$v_1 = d_2v_2 + ... d_sv_s$, for some $d_i \in \mathbb{C}$.
We know $v_1 \in N((A - \lambda_1I)^{n_1})$, so above gives, $d_2v_2 + ... d_sv_s \in N((A - \lambda_1I)^{n_1})$, which has to be true for any $d_i \in \mathbb{C}$.
$\implies v_2, ..., v_s \in N((A - \lambda_1I)^{n_1})$.

*Lemma:*
$N((A - \lambda_iI)^{n_i}) \cap N((A - \lambda_jI)^{n_j}) = \{0\}$

*Proof of Lemma:*
Here is where I get stuck. I figure if I get this result I can show that we arrive at some contradiction above as $v_2,...,v_s$ must be zero. So then I will have i). But still, I can't show this Lemma for the life of me.

Sorry if this was a long post, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You did not define what your $v_i$ were ; and probably you wanted to write $v_i\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and not $v_i\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you, a miss on my part. It should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

For your lemma, I don't know if it's one of those arguments that are too advanced for your taste, but I really don't see how you can prove this without using Bézout's theorem one way or another.

So write $U(X)\cdot (X-\lambda_i)^{n_i} + V(X)\cdot (X-\lambda_j)^{n_j} = 1$ with $U,V\in \mathbb{C}[X]$.

Then if $x\in N((A - \lambda_iI)^{n_i}) \cap N((A - \lambda_jI)^{n_j})$, you get $$x = U(A)((A - \lambda_iI)^{n_i}(x)) + V(A)((A - \lambda_jI)^{n_j}(x)) = U(A)(0) + V(A)(0) = 0.$$

Comment: I'm afraid it is. I don't understand the language you use. What is $U(X)$, $X$ and $V(X)$?